# Can Mac App Store Sandboxed apps use CGEventPost?

Tags: macos, events, sandbox, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

For an app I am working on I am using `CGEventPost` to post some key events and I noticed that it stopped working with sandboxing enabled, even I turned on the "Enable Access for Assistive Devices" system preference.

Is there an entitlement to allow the use of `CGEventPost`? Or, is there another way to post key events with apps submitted to the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can Mac App Store Sandboxed apps use CGEventPost?

No.

> Is there an entitlement for CGEventPost? Or is there any way to post key events with apps submitted to the Mac App Store?

No.

If you look at the developer forums, Apple has made it very clear that they will never enable an entitlement for this, because it allows a blatantly obvious way for any app to escape the sandbox.

If you have some more specific need that you can justify (not "post some key events" but "get iPhoto do to XXX, which as far as I know can only be done by posting event YYY at it"), file a bug report, and post a thread on the dev forums.

This will do two things:

1. Someone at Apple may suggest a workaround--possibly a private one that nobody else can tell you and/or one that isn't normally allowed on the App Store but will be accepted if you've been told to use it.
2. It increases the chances that Apple will invent some better way to do what you want in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but accepted answer is wrong. There are apps in Mac App Store that are using CGEventPost to simulate events. For example apps "Remote Mouse" and "Mobile Mouse Server" do that. They can send input to any other app and based on symbols in those apps they are clearly using CGEventPost-function. I would like to know how are they doing it.

Comment: If you download both of your mentioned apps you will see they are not sandboxed. I am assuming that they submitted them to apple before Sandboxing was enforced and have just submitted bug fixes since then (which is allowed per Apple's sandboxing rules). So I am assuming that they are using CGEventPost - which is not allowed for any new app on the Mac App Store. I have emailed the creators though, just in case, to see what it is they are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So rules are not the same for all apps then.

Comment: Sandboxing was not required until June 1, 2012. Any app submitted after that date must be sandboxed. Any app before that date can stay on the App Store in an un-sandboxed mode but only bug fixes can be submitted to Apple. They are not allowed to do any feature updates.

Comment: Yeah and if I want to write similar app like Remote Mouse I cannot distribute it via Mac App Store and even more I cannot autorun it at system startup!? It is stupid.

Comment: I found two new apps which have the sandbox entitlement: "Computer Mouse" (com.highsolutions.iPhoneMouse) and "Remmo" (com.applace.remmo).

Comment: @DimitarNestorov yeah... something going on and I'm not sure what. Seems like some app get accepted while they use this or similar API to simulate user input.

Comment: I know for sure that `CGEventTapPostEvent` works in sandboxed apps, but you need to be granted permission in System Settings > Privacy & Security > Accessibility.  CGRequestPostEventAccess asks the user for that permission.